# Inapropriate Migration

Tags: discussion, migration

This question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/244984/what-features-should-be-look-for-when-evaluating-usb-batteries-for-all-day-use-i was recently migrated from this SE to the electronics SE.

While I can't make any judgement as to its on/off topic-ness here since I don't participate in this site, it is off topic there (one of the canned close-vote options is "Use of commercial product is off topic" and has already attracted 4 close votes, no new comments (other than the ones from this site) and no answers.

So Mods here - please try to be at least minimally familiar with the on/off topic policies of the site(s) you migrate questions to.

Answer (score 3):

> While I can't make any judgement as to its on/off topic-ness here since I don't participate in this site ...

Exactly. We can't make any judgement as to its on/off topic-ness *there* since we don't participate in that site.

But it was certainly off topic here, since it has *nothing* to do with bicycles. So instead of giving us a poke how about doing something positive, such as advising where you think it *should* go?

The description of [electronics.se] seemed apt:

> Q&A for electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts

Perhaps you need to add the words *non commercial* to the description.

Or maybe, address this question *what's wrong with explaining the criteria for battery evaluation*? If you don't do it, then who will?

Answer (score 1):

Well, we can't be familiar with *every* SE's policies. At best, you can only expect people to migrate things to the closest SE by description and let them sort it out (or close it here).

You could try a different SE if you think there is one that fits better than electronics (e.g. one that is for your application), if it exists, or a forum for people interested in your application.